# android/ java - wait for return from time a consuming method ( ex: apicall ) then execute other code

Tags: java, android, synchronization

isHoliday() method always return false. the problem is before checkIsAnyOffDay() method finished , isHoliday() had returned.  that's why isHoliday() always return false. I need to finished checkIsAnyOffDay() then return. How could this be done. would you please help me?

```
private boolean isHoliday() {
        final boolean[] feedback = {false};
        ApiManager.checkIsAnyOffDay(new ApiManager.OnApiResponse() {
            @Override
            public void onSucceed(ApiResponse data) {
                 
                feedback[0] = true;

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailed(String errorMsg) {
                 
                feedback[0] = false;
            }
        });
        return feedback[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For async operations you need to create callback. You can find an example below.

```
interface Response<T> {
    public void onFinish(T result);
}

private void isHoliday(final Response<Boolean> callback) {
    ApiManager.checkIsAnyOffDay(new ApiManager.OnApiResponse() {
        @Override
        public void onSucceed(ApiResponse data) {
            callback.onFinish(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(String errorMsg) {

            callback.onFinish(false);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for your valuable answer. I would like to ask some question to clear my concept. Is it mandatory to create callback or there are other option available also? like wait() and notify() or something else....?

Comment: For async operations on Java, callback is best option. You can also check [Kotlin coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines)